Unable to update Managed Metadata column
I have a SharePoint site where I can not save the values in any managed metadata column.
What happens:

I go to managed metadata column
Select a term
"Saving" message shows up
After saving the term disappers and the column stays empty
The "last modified" time stemp updates as if I would had added and
deleted the term


Troubleshooting so far:

Issue only occurs on one Teams-connected SharePoint site, other sites
are not effected
Issue occurs only with managed metadata columns
Tested multiple manually created columns and columns from content
types
Tested in new library on the same site -> same issue (So it really
seams as if the whole site would be effected)
Teste multiple term sets
Deleted browser cache
Tested multiple browsers, etc.


We do not have the issue on other sites of ours and I don't think there was anything set up differently here.
Any ideas why does this happening?

I couldn't reproduce this issue in my site. This seems not to be a common issue. I suggest you open a ticket with Microsoft and let them help you check from the backend.
